# Swapping click and middle click buttons

Tags: xorg, mouse, xinput

Is there a way to swap click and middle click buttons permanently in Kubuntu?

```
    $xinput list 
    Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ cx88 IR (Leadtek Winfast 2000XP           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please append the output of `xinput list` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting the ID of your mouse:**

You can get it running `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 046a:0023                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G9x Laser Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G9x Laser Mouse                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 046a:0023                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have two mouse IDs (10 and 11), therefore I have to test the right ID.

---

**Swapping the buttons:**

You can swap the mouse buttons running this (where `10` is the ID):

```
xinput set-button-map 10 2 1 3
```

You can revert the change with:

```
xinput set-button-map 10 1 2 3
```

---

**Swap the buttons automatically when X starts:**

- Run this command to edit the *91swapmousebuttons* file:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/91swapmousebuttons
  ```
- Add this line to it:

  ```
  xinput set-button-map 10 2 1 3
  ```

---

**Explaination of the parameters passed to xinput:**

- `set-button-map` changes the button map of a device.
- `10` is the device ID.
- `2 1 3` means:

  - `2`: It's on the 1st position, so the first button (<kbd>LMB</kbd>) is mapped to button 2 (<kbd>MMB</kbd>).
  - `1`:  It's on the 2nd position, so the second button (<kbd>MMB</kbd>) is mapped to button 1 (<kbd>LMB</kbd>).
  - `1`:  It's on the 3rd position, so the third button (<kbd>RMB</kbd>) is mapped to button 3 (<kbd>LMB</kbd>).

Note that <kbd>LMB</kbd> is **L**eft **M**ouse **B**utton, <kbd>MMB</kbd> is **M**id **M**ouse **B**utton and so on.

Quote from `man xinput`:

> Change  the  button mapping of device. The buttons are specified in
>   physical order (starting with button 1) and are mapped to the logical
>   button provided. 0 disables a button. The default button mapping for a
>   device is 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc.

Comment: @Helio Nice phrasing :) "Aggresively improved formatting"  thanks for the improvement :)

Comment: No offence, but I very much doubt that xinput command will work from `Xsession.d`. Did you test it? But a great answer anyway.

Comment: @Helio Did you test that 'Xsession.d' script?

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't.

Comment: I did and it does not. I would suggest to move it to `/etc/xdg/autostart`. But .desktop file is needed there.

Comment: @Helio I did and it does not. I would suggest to move it to /etc/xdg/autostart. But .desktop file is needed there.